# .NET Elastic Search inmemory mocking

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, tdd

on a new project we are trying to define our TDD schema and we're looking for a way to mock an Elastic Search server inmemory. 
Any idea on a Nuget or a way that would help us do that?

Edit: to clarify the question , we're looking for something like that in .net : https://github.com/sgmarghade/mock-elasticsearch-server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock then what is topping you? If you are using [NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) then you should use interface IElasticClient which you can mock.

Using [nsubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) you can do following (this is not working code its just pseudo code which will give you idea what to do)

```
var client = Substitute.For<IElasticClient>();
client.Search(Args.Any()).Returns(info => new MockResult());
var controller = new MyControllerOrService(client)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But in fact we're looking for something like that in .net : https://github.com/sgmarghade/mock-elasticsearch-server